# calculate turning acceleration from a compass

Tags: mathematics, compass

I have degree and timestamp and want to calculate the turning acceleration. What to trigger if the compass is turning fast.
Is there a mathematic way to get an acceleration parameter?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @MagnusOsbeck! Are you asking for the [angular acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_acceleration) of a compass pointer? This is probably better asked in [Physics:SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Rather than a "degree", you'll probably want to posit "an angle (in degrees)".  Distance is also necessary, and a direction of travel.

Comment: I want to find a way to calculate the rotation speed when the phone is in upright position. The device motion can't handle that direction. That is why i'm trying to us the compass. The phone will move around and the the degree will change, it's only when the phone is turning fast I want to trigger code. That is why i need the acceleration parameter. 
explained in code: if compass.turningAcceleration >= myValue ? runMyCode ;)